# Avoid the character jumping because of capsule collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

My unity game have a character with a capsule collider. When the character hit another collider on the spherical part of the capsule, the character is send in the air. How to avoid that?

[Here is a video to explain the problem](https://youtu.be/62bKT-lf8C0)

I already have some solutions but it doesn't really work:

- Use a cylinder collider instead of capsule, but it doesn't exist. I tried to make one with meshcollider and the result is not as good as a caspule collider since the meshcollider is not perfectly rounded. I also tried to make one with many rect collider but it produce same problems as meshcollider.
- Set a really big gravity force when the character is on the ground, but the problem is that I have inclined planes in the game, so it doesn't work neither.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah, I feel ya on this one.

Comment: Do you have any idea i should try?

Comment: Not really.  I moved the capsule collider further up and added additional capsule colliders on the feet.  Seemed a little better.  If you go with Rigidbody movement there is always CharacterController or other scripts out there.

Comment: How you're moving your character? Rigidbody? If so, using velocity, MovePosition or what? Please, share you code and character settings so we can help.

Comment: It doesn't need code because this is the expected behaviour from unity. I am just looking for suggestion or idea to solve this problem, and more precisely to overcome the fact that unity has no collider cylinder.

Comment: have you seen that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peqvspqMakk

Comment: @Frenchy Yes I tried, but it's not a real pipe like in a capsule, and it produce bad behaviour when my character hit a wall. Moreover, if I add many boxes, performance gets bad..

Answer (score 2):

I might not be right but I think you should delete the capsule collider and add a Mesh Collider or you could also just add colliders to each part of the player which would take longer but I think that's what you're needing. So add sphere colliders to the head, box colliders to the arms and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can propably fix the unwanted behavior:

- with a different physics material for your colliders. Removing bounciness may help.
- by adjusting scales of your objects.
- by changing the collider of the ground from a box collider with sharp edges to a mesh collider with slopes on the edges.
- by adding a code that will snap your character to the ground.

There is a great tutorial on character movement from Catlike Coding I can recommend: [A series about controlling the movement of a character.](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/movement/)